# How to change main file for webpack module

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Require.js modules and every module has main.js main file instead of index.js. How can i override this in webpack config?

```
  modulesDirectories: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'dev/app/screens/test-screen')
  ],
```

dev/app/screens/test-screen/main.js should be called when i am resolving require('screens/test-screen')

I am trying to use packageMains but with no success for now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way i found is do this

```
alias: {
  'screens/test-screen$': 'screens/test-screen/main.coffee'
}
```

Not the best solution because i have pass it for every module but it works